# PHP: Reverse lookup in JSON by searchfind value in key, Planradar API

Tags: php, json, reverse-lookup

I currently have the challenge of performing a reverse search in PHP for a JSON. I´m looking for value "ogwoaml" in Key "user-id". Then I need to check if "id" of this Object with Keys is "bonwbono".
[Screenshot of JSON-Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8bWE.png)

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "bonwbono",
            "type": "journals",
            "attributes": {
                "id": "bonwbono",
                "notes": "Handwerker sind am 30.11.2023...",
                "created-on": "2023-11-30T21:12:10.823Z",
                "journalized-id": "xmbmmbzl",
                "user-id": "ogwoaml"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "journal-details": {
                    "data": []
                },
                "user": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "ogwoaml",
                        "type": "users"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "delnjepz",
            "type": "journals",
            "attributes": {
                "id": "delnjepz",
                "notes": null,
                "created-on": "2023-11-30T21:11:08.825Z",
                "journalized-id": "xmbmmbzl",
                "user-id": "ogwoaml"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "journal-details": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "id": "lyngjyag",
                            "type": "journal-details"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "user": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "ogwoaml",
                        "type": "users"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be honest. I have taught myself HTML, PHP, SQL JSON and have already mastered many challenges, but unfortunately I am currently missing an approach to mastering this challenge. I hope for strong impulses from the community.

Basically handling of JSON in PHP is quite clear.

```
$obj = json_decode($value);
$foo = $obj -> data -> 0 -> attributes-> user-id;
```

End of day I need to filter how many times we have id:"bonwbono" and user-id:"ogwoaml" in same Object with Keys. The snipped code is only part of in total approx 75 issues.

Comment: What, if any, is the error you're getting? Or is it just not finding it?
For a start you're using object notation on your arrays.
You'd be better off using: $obj = json_decode($value, true);
And then you can use the multitude of PHP array methods to search.

Comment: A couple of issues: firstly, arrays remain arrays even when using `json_decode` to generate an object. Secondly, you need to escape `user-id` as it's not a valid identifier. What you need is [`$foo = $obj -> data[0] -> attributes-> {'user-id'};`](https://3v4l.org/kvNXp)

Comment: Thank you, your right with {'user-id'}. End of day I need to filter how many times we have id:"bonwbono" and user-id:"ogwoaml" in same Object with Keys. The snipped code is only part of JSON.